# Error Loading Wallpaper

Tags: 11.10, desktop-background

[image]When i press "ctrl+alt+f3" it goes in cli mode

and then when i press "ctrl+alt+f7" error loading wallpaper

All things are working properly

just my desktop wallpaper seems to be crashed

Comment: & how do i paste my pics here so u can see what is the real problem

Comment: Click "edit", then img in the toolbar. Upload the picture and click save edits

Comment: Your'e Welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem just yesterday. I removed all my nautilus plugins, thinking that was the problem - but it seemed not to be.

In the end, I ended up noticing that the Desktop had been disabled all together. If you have GNOME-Tweak tool or Ubuntu-Tweak installed, re-enable the option to display Desktop icons, and your Desktop wallpaper will return.

*Let me know if you need any further assistance in the comments.*

Answer (score 0):

Are you running 11.04 or 11.10?

Try restarting nautilus with:

`nautilus -q`

That will quit your current nautilus session. If it doesn't restart automatically, you can run nautilus from the terminal or open a folder. This should work and be less extreme than completely restarting X.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ubuntu desktop 11.10